# Didn't find intValueExact for BigInt in Scala

Tags: scala, math, bigint

`java.math.BigInteger` has methods like `intValueExact`, which throws an exception in case of overflow. The scala class `scala.math.BigInt` seems not to have such methods.

Should I do something like this ?

```
def intExact(num: BigInt): Int = if (num.isValidInt) num.toInt else // throw an exception
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[scala.math.BigInt](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5cb672bdc6e8a662ddc68a07811956e78a134acf/src/library/scala/math/BigInt.scala#L112) is just a thin wrapper around java.math.BigInteger. So you can just do the following (on Java8) without any performance problems

```
scala> val x: BigInt = 1
x: BigInt = 1

scala> x.bigInteger.intValueExact
res0: Int = 1
```

Assuming you are OK with this throwing an exception. Otherwise use what @jazmit has suggested.

Note: if you want a really fast arbitrary precision integer, I would recommend using [spire.math.SafeLong](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/spire/stable/0.11.0/unidoc/#spire.math.SafeLong). It uses a Long under the hood as long as the number is small enough, so it will be really fast in many common situations.

SafeLong has a method isValidLong to check if the value fits into a long.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the right thing to do.. if you want to throw an exception on failure.  The 'scala' way to do things would be to return an option, so that the error can be processed in a more functional way:

```
def intExact(num: BigInt): Option[Int] = if (num.isValidInt) Some(num.toInt) else None
```